# Postgresql Alter Column in Idempotent Way

Tags: postgresql, ddl, idempotent

I'm writing a database script that involves this simple line

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE varchar(50);
```

How can I make this idempotent? I can't seem to figure out if there's an `ON CONFLICT` or `IF EXISTS` clause I should add to get this to not error out on subsequent runs. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check `information_schema.columns`.  Demo script:

```sql
drop table if exists my_table;

create table my_table (my_column int);

-- vvvvv alter column idempotently vvvvv
do $$
begin
    
if not exists (
    select 1
    from information_schema."columns"
    where table_name               = 'my_table'
      and column_name              = 'my_column'
      and data_type                = 'character varying'
      and character_maximum_length = 50)
then
    alter table my_table alter column my_column type varchar(50);
    raise notice 'altered the column definition';
else
    raise notice 'data type is already correct';
end if;

end $$;
-- ^^^^^ alter column idempotently ^^^^^

-- Run that same block of code again...
do $$
begin
    
if not exists (
    select 1
    from information_schema."columns"
    where table_name               = 'my_table'
      and column_name              = 'my_column'
      and data_type                = 'character varying'
      and character_maximum_length = 50)
then
    alter table my_table alter column my_column type varchar(50);
    raise notice 'altered the column definition';
else
    raise notice 'data type is already correct';
end if;

end $$;
```

And the results:

```
altered the column definition
data type is already correct
```